# Send Parcelable object to another activity

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable

I got 3 classes. Series, Season and Episodes.
The Series class got a list of Season objects and the Season class got a list of Episode objects.

I want to send the Series object to the other activity like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("series", (Parcelable)seriesObject);
```

But I get a NullPointerException.

Here are the classes that implements Parcelable.

Series class:

```
public class Series implements Parcelable {

private int seasonCount;
public ArrayList<Season>seasons;
private String seriesName;
private int lastSeenSeason = 0;
private int lastSeenEpisode = 0;

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(seasonCount);
    dest.writeTypedList(seasons);
    dest.writeString(seriesName);
    dest.writeInt(lastSeenSeason);
    dest.writeInt(lastSeenEpisode);
}

private Series(Parcel in){
    seasonCount = in.readInt();
    in.readTypedList(seasons, Season.CREATOR);
    seriesName = in.readString();
    lastSeenSeason = in.readInt();
    lastSeenEpisode = in.readInt();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Series> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Series>() {
    public Series createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Series(in);
    }
    public Series[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Series[size];
    }
};
```

Season class:

```
public class Season implements Parcelable{

private int seasonNo;
private int episodeCount;
public ArrayList<Episode> episodes;


public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(seasonNo);
    dest.writeInt(episodeCount);
    dest.writeTypedList(episodes);
}

private Season(Parcel in){
    this.seasonNo = in.readInt();
    episodeCount = in.readInt();
    in.readTypedList(episodes, Episode.CREATOR);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Season> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Season>() {
    public Season createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Season(in);
    }
    public Season[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Season[size];
    }
};
```

and the Episode class:

```
public class Episode implements Parcelable{

private int episodeNo;
private boolean episodeSeen;


public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(episodeNo);
    dest.writeByte((byte) (episodeSeen ? 1 : 0));
}

private Episode(Parcel in){
    episodeNo = in.readInt();
    episodeSeen = in.readByte() != 0;
}


public static final Parcelable.Creator<Episode> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Episode>() {
    public Episode createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Episode(in);
    }
    public Episode[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Episode[size];
    }
};
```

Comment: You should post your stack trace.

Comment: However, this line may cause it: in.readTypedList(seasons, Season.CREATOR); seasons have not initialized that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize your arrays:

```
public ArrayList<Episode> episodes = new ArrayList<Episode>();
public ArrayList<Season> seasons = new ArrayList<Season>();
```

otherwise `readTypedList` will fail.

Comment: I initialized my lists in my public constructor so I didn't think about this thx!